# .htaccess Redirect + Rewrite in one rule

Tags: .htaccess

1. I have a rewrite rule to hide index.php, which is
   working fine.

   ```
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php) 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
   ```
2. I am currently redirecting a specific sub-domain to another domain.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?deutschland\.example\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.de%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
   ```

The redirect is working fine, but now I am getting index.php in the URL too, which is coming in the REQUEST_URI.

```
http://www.example.de/index.php/search/result
```

So how to remove 'index.php' from this redirected URL?
Note: Its the same php website application only, just using country-wise multiple domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Rule order is important. (2) the `last` flag doesn't mean last; it means last on this cycle.  (From Apache 2.4 the end flag does what you might think last does.  See my [Tips for debugging .htaccess rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules) for more discussion of this). So in this case rule(1) fires and then mod_rewrite loops around again and this time rule (2) fires giving what you find.

Swap the two rules around and it will work as expected.